# Error auto Ctrl+C when choosing text in VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, fedora, vmware-player

Now I have a problem in VM-ware virtual machine that I enter left mouse to choose a text then I free left mouse **ctrl+c** command auto implement. This make me very difficult when using terminal. 
has anybody met this problem. Please help me.

Many thanks.